# How do I show the "Your Cart" link in my Rules message

Tags: commerce, rules

I have a created a rule in drupal commerce.  I want to include a link to the users cart in that message, just like the link that appears when you add a product to the cart.  When I use the url token, the message displays like this: This item has been removed from `http://dcomm/user/3/orders/6.`

I want it to be --This item has been removed from your cart. and you click on the "your cart" and be taken to your cart view.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a link to

```
<a href="/cart">your cart</a>
```

It will show the user's shopping cart.

Comment: Grief - talk about over thinking something.  Thank you!!!!